# Converting varchar datatype in database to Array property in read model

Tags: c#

I am looking for an elegant way of mapping a

`varchar datatype(False,False,False,True,False,False,False)`

to

`IEnumerable<bool>` property in my read model.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Most of the solutions I found point to JsonConvert attribute for the property.

```
    public class myClass 
    {
        public IEnumerable<bool> myList { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What part do you need to be "easier"?

Comment: You mention JsonConvert - is your input with the boolean string list actually Json to start with? Do you *want* a solution using JsonConvert, or if not, what exactly is the context you need to perform this conversion in?

Comment: By easier I meant if there is a way to handle this from getter method itself?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input string looks like

```
string input = "(False,False,False,True,False,False,False)";
```

and have always a leading `'('` and trailing `')'` and is separated by a `','`.

Under this conditions you can use [`string.Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.8) to remove the braces and [`string.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) to separate each value into an array of strings.

You can now loop over the array and use [`bool.Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.parse?view=netframework-4.8) to parse each element into a boolean.

This could be done in a short way with `System.Linq`

```
using System.Linq;

//...

string input = "(False,False,False,True,False,False,False)";
List<bool> result = 
    input.Trim('(',')')                // Remove the leading and trailing braces
         .Split(',')                   // Split all values by ',' into an array
         .Select(bv => bool.Parse(bv)) // and convert them into a Boolean value
         .ToList();                    // materialize them as a List if you need
```

Result:

```
List<bool>(7) { false, false, false, true, false, false, false }
```

Comment: Input would be a string like "False,False,False,True,False,False,False". Thanks for your response. Is there a way to handle this from getter method itself?

Comment: @maskedmenace: How do you receive your string - via DataReader or something else? Can you add the code which shows how you get your data?